# Screenshot not similar to Display view

Tags: java, android, image, screenshot, rounded-corners

I take a screenshot of a layout but giving image not similar to display runtime view.
I used `com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView` library for pinch to zoom gesture on image.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ContentLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/random"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/ImageViewLeftCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
                android:id="@+id/ImageViewLeft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blackcolor"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/ImageViewRightCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
                android:id="@+id/ImageViewRight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/blackcolor" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I need image after screenshot as same as display view.

I am taking screenshot with this code.

```
private void screenshot(View v){
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

The problem i facing.. in simple wordings that i need image with rounded corners after screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private Bitmap extractBitmap(ViewGroup iViewGroup) {

int width = iViewGroup.getWidth();
int height = iViewGroup.getWidth();

Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(createBitmap);

iViewGroup.draw(canvas);

return createBitmap;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable resource

**round_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

and set this drawable as background for **com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ContentLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/random"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewLeftCard"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/ImageViewLeft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
            android:background="@color/blackcolor" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewRightCard"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/ImageViewRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
            android:background="@color/blackcolor" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And use the same function you are using to get the screenshot.